# Docusign - Unable to get User GUIID using Users::list API

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Once, a user has given Consent to my application for impersonation and signature I should be able to retrieve there User Data using `Users:list` API. But it is only returning only the developer accounts data.

The user whose data I'm trying to retrieve, I logged into that account and the APP was mentioned in Connected Apps Tab.

What is probably going wrong, here?

https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Users&tags=Users&operations=list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That endpoint will only return users within the account specified, a user who has granted consent to a particular app is not counted as a user in said apps account.

Comment: How should one retrieve that data?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the user's basic information and you're impersonating them, use the [/oauth/userinfo API method](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/).

What information are you looking for?

Comment: The problem was I assumed I don't need to use Authorization code grant, I can handle everything using JWT Grant. But it seems the JWT grant is somehow dependent on Authorization Code Grant, till we get the user GUIID using the above method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433671/docusign-trying-to-get-userinfo-after-consent-received-internal-server-error