# Docusign: Trying to get userInfo after consent received internal_server_error

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Used the token, received after giving consent on the API explorer.

https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/authentication/restapi?categories=Authentication&tags=OAuth&operations=getUserInfo

error: "internal_server_error"
reference_id: "a9291605-10a3-4674-9a76-219d56f6dd07"

I have checked the integrator key which has been used, the Authorization Code Grant is enabled
on it. What I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Edit -

The error I had was that the OAuth 2.0 flow, I used the Implicit Code Grant and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens you get from API Explorer were not meant to be used by you elsewhere.
You need to obtain a token by building your own OAuth 2.0 flow.
This error basically says the token is invalid for what you are trying to do with it.